# Es posible guardar libro de trabajo de excel en vsto c#?

Tags: c#, excel

estoy buscando como asignar la opción de guardar libro de trabajo a un botón. como la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente con esto pero no me guarda el libro de trabajo actual solo me genera uno nuevo.

```
    var saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog() //create new instance of savefiledialog
{  
    Title = "Save As", //sets title of dialog box
    Filter = "Excel Worbook (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx", //filter for .xlsx files
    AddExtension = true, //automatically adds the .xlsx extension
    CheckPathExists = true //checks if the given path really exists
}

if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(saveDialog.FileName);
}
```

Comment: Si podes intenta explicar un poco mejor el problema, al menos a mi no me queda claro!